# Not able to open RSViewerPage.aspx page in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, reporting-services, report-viewer

I need to customize SharePoint Reports and show bar charts on it and do some customization's on it.

I am trying to open following URL in SharePoint Designer 2013,

```
http://SITEURL/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx
```

but, it is giving me an error,

> URL is not valid.

Why does that happen? Can anybody tell me about customization of `RSViewerPage.apsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is in the "15 hive" as other users have mentioned. At a practical level what this means is that it's stored in the file system on the servers (typically under C:\Program Files\common Files\microsoft shared\web Server Extensions\15). You can potentially modify the file there, but note that this will change how RSViewerPage.apsx works everywhere in your SharePoint farm.

This is a bad idea, it's not officially supported, it can prevent future updates or future updates will overwrite your changes.

A much better way to do it is to create your own brand new page. You can include all the changes you want on it, and include stuff from reporting services using the reporting services web parts (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326362.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is unsupported as the file resides in the 15 hive and is updated by SSRS.

Comment: Yeah ok, but what is the way to customize it then.

Comment: You can't. Customizing it would prevent further updates to the file from patching. This page just displays reports, there should be no reason to customize it.

Comment: But, I have the requirement to show some charts on that page, and one logo alongwith one label on that. So can this happen is there any way.

Comment: Is that we cant customize any page in 15 hive folder. Would you please elaborate briefly, since I am new to sharepoint 2013 reports

Comment: You would want to put the SSRS report in a webpart. This way you can add it to a page to show your RDL (report). And no, making direct edits to the 15 hive files is unsupported for two reasons: The files will not update when a patch is released (because the modified date is different), thus you could have a situation where you leave a security vulnerability open, and two because those changes do not replicate to all servers in the farm.